# How does this function create a deep neural network and not just rename the same variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm self learning from Geron's "Hands on Machine Learning" and I'm a little confused about how this function (in box [114] of the following page) creates a deep neural network.

https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/11_deep_learning.ipynb

```
he_init = tf.variance_scaling_initializer()

def dnn(inputs, n_hidden_layers=5, n_neurons=100, name=None,
        activation=tf.nn.elu, initializer=he_init):
    with tf.variable_scope(name, "dnn"):
        for layer in range(n_hidden_layers):
            inputs = tf.layers.dense(inputs, n_neurons, activation=activation,
                                     kernel_initializer=initializer,
                                     name="hidden%d" % (layer + 1))
        return inputs
```

It just looks like it resets the same input each time with a different name.  Can someone explain how this is supposed to create a deep neural network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a strong misconception about model construction in TensorFlow. You are advised to read more about TensorFlow's computational graph and other low-level details of this API in the [official guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/low_level_intro).

Operations built using TensorFlow are not bound to a Python variable
(assume that we are not in Eager mode for this answer). When calling one of the layer construction functions in `tf.layers` (or other basic functions such as the ones in `tf.nn`), that will add new operations to the currently active graph and return the `Tensor` corresponding to the output of that layer. The operations do not disappear when removing or altering the contents of the Python variables that used to hold these tensors.

What the function `dnn` does is iteratively create a sequence of dense layers. At each step, the variable `inputs` is changed to point to the output of the most recently created layer, allowing it to be "fed" into the next one. Whether to use the same variable as the original inputs or a new one for this is a matter of opinion (I often use a new variable `net` myself). By default, this will result in a sequence of 5 fully connected layers. Only the graph was constructed in all this; no network training or weight initialization procedures were actually applied here.

This can also be validated visually. The following code will write the graph's signature to a TensorFlow summary file:

```
he_init = tf.variance_scaling_initializer()

def dnn(inputs, n_hidden_layers=5, n_neurons=100, name=None,
        activation=tf.nn.elu, initializer=he_init):
    with tf.variable_scope(name, "dnn"):
        for layer in range(n_hidden_layers):
            inputs = tf.layers.dense(inputs, n_neurons, activation=activation,
                                     kernel_initializer=initializer,
                                     name="hidden%d" % (layer + 1))
        return inputs

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [32, 128])
y = dnn(x)
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='mydnn', graph=tf.get_default_graph())
writer.flush()
```

By opening the same log directory with TensorBoard, we get the following graph:

[image]